# Sharing an Angular 2 service between child components who don't share the same parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

Let's say I have an Angular 2 that is structured as follows:

[image]

In other words, there is a root parent component `A` that contains instances of two distinct children components `B` and `C`.

Now say I want to create a `MyService` class to be shared across each vertical column of children components. More specifically, I want to be able to inject `MyService` into component `B` and component `C`'s constructors, with Angular creating two instances of the service overall (one for the first column of child components and another for the second column of child components).

One way to do this is to wrap each column of child components in a intermediate component `P` and then declare `MyService` as a provider in its `@Component` decorator using `providers: [MyService]`. This ensures that each instance of `P` (and therefore all of its children components as well) will receive their own instance of `MyService`:

[image]

However, I would like to avoid this solution because creating an intermediary wrapper component like this seems like a lot of extra boiler plate and it also requires restructuring how components are laid out in component `A`'s template.

Is there an easy way to achieve this in Angular 2? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent component that hosts the injector and `MyService` provider is the correct solution. This is how Angular 2 DI works. Even if there were a singleton service, `MyServiceFactory` that can create `MyService` class instances, how would it determine that `B` and `C` should receive a common `MyService` instance, considering that there are several `B`s and `C`s?

Parent component is preferable, unless there are unresolvable layout issues. Otherwise it can be a directive with `MyService` provider,

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[p]',
  providers: [MyService]
})
class P {}
```

that results in transparent layout with

```
<ng-container p>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
</ng-container>
<ng-container p>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `ng-container`... will try that out!

Comment: On second thought... I still don't see how the `ng-container` could be used in this case. For example, what if I want to share an instance of the service between the top left `B` component and the bottom right `C` component? Reshuffling the template layout for the purposes of getting dependency injection to work the way I want it to doesn't sound like a very flexible solution to me (i.e. what if I need to change my template layout significantly later?). Is there a way I can somehow specify these groupings without requiring them to belong to the same DOM node and/or `ng-container`?

Comment: Angular isn't 'flexible', it is opinionated. If you know how it works good enough, you can design the app in efficient way and know what to expect. Until then design issues may appear, they are parts of learning curve.

Comment: *share an instance of the service between the top left B component and the bottom right C component*, this condition sounds wrong to me and differs from what was stated in the question. There's no good way to do that in A2 in a chosen way, most likely you have XY problem. I would suggest to ask a new question and be very specific on what problems you try to solve here, including the ones that are related to layout. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is welcome.

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvgs2vwdjeq8bxh/Screenshot%202017-01-17%2002.15.46.png?dl=0) of the app I'm building. The three canvases at the top are instances of component `B` and the two cards at the bottom are instances of component `C`. I want to create a service that can be shared between the top/bottom left components and the top/bottom right components. However, as you can see the app's current row-based layout makes creating a parent container for these two pairs of children components difficult. Does that make more sense what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: By the way... the main reason I ask this question is mainly just because my current setup feels really clunky and awkward. I currently have a singleton service that is shared across all of the children components... which means every time a child components calls a method on the service, it must also pass in extra information in order to identify itself (i.e. "I'm the top left child component" or "I'm the bottom right child component", etc.). If there was a way to customize how the service instances are created and shared amongst child components, it would make the code much more readable.

Comment: It definitely shouldn't be solved with DI. It likely should be a single service instance that holds all data for all `B`s and `C`s. Probably `Map` or `WeakMap`. The way how data is identified (key) and how unused data is removed to avoid memory leaks really depends on the details.

Comment: Yeah that is essentially what I am doing right now. I disagree that it shouldn't be solved with DI... because if it were easily possible for me to wrap the children components in a parent component that provides the service, the Di would work perfectly. It sounds like it might not be possible to achieve this without creating a wrapping container however?

Comment: No, it may be not. That's how Angular compiler works. If Angular DI doesn't suit your case completely, it shouldn't be used this way, I guess. There are always several ways to do the same thing. E.g. a single parent component can just pass relevant data objects to all Bs and Cs through bindings. Btw, components can be shuffled with flex while keeping their structure in desired shape.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I don't want to get too off topic but is [this layout](http://i.imgur.com/hhVQdrn.jpg) something that you think is possible to achieve using flex? I'm pretty new to web stuff so just want to make sure I'm not about to go off on the completely wrong track here. :P If not, then maybe you are right and the best solution would be to just pass the data objects to the children via bindings.

Comment: From the question it may seem that it is about uniform structures, like tables or grids. For limited amount of components per layout the bindings look like the best bet. Yes, it may be achievable with flex, it depends if component sizes are fixed/scaled, etc, but ng-container suits this case nicely.

Comment: I suppose I'll accept this answer for now since I wasn't able to come up with a better solution. If anything changes on this front, let me know. :)

Comment: I don't think that something will change from DI perspective, this part of Angular was already established, but I surely will.

Comment: Just a question . If I configure the injector of P (wrapper component) to provide a service lets say MyService and I inject the service in the constructor of P . Further if I inject the service in the constructors of both A and B as well . Then will A and B get the same instance of MyService ? and will that instance be the same as the one which was provided to P (the parent component) . ?

Comment: @RishavMahapatra That's correct, that's how hierarchical injector works.

Comment: Thanks and I just saw it is actually clearly given in the official angular website under "DI in Action" [link](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action)

Answer (score 0):

And what about a static EventEmitter both components subscribe to ?

I saw that somewhere, one day (if I remember I'll put a link). I use it right now without visible drawback, I'll see when the app grows.

```
//the "commands dispatcher" class :

import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class CommandsDispatcherService {
  private static store: { [channel: string]: EventEmitter<any> } = {};

  static get(channel: string): EventEmitter<any> {
    if (!this.store[channel]) {
      this.store[channel] = new EventEmitter();
    }
    return this.store[channel];
  }
}
```

Components A & B (without any hierarchical relationship) just import the class (no provider), subscribe to it on init and use the get method to communicate with each other on their own private channel. I found that pretty cool.